# How to Generate Access Token Including Claims in Identity Server 4 Microservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

Duende identity server / identity server 4 problems.
I want to implement simple identity microservice (Web API, no quick start pages). So I need login method in controller to return access token. But how correctly generate it (i want it to include claims like role, id number). Also i implemented profile service, but still don't know where it used in a pipeline or smth like that. Already watch and read lots of resources - no answers

Lots of interfaces, provided by these libs, but not sure they work at all